# connect two vpn server

Tags: linux, openvpn, linux-networking

I have 2 VPS in 2 locations.  The first vps is located in Iran and has the ip : A.A.A.A.  The second vps is located in the USA and has the ip : B.B.B.B.

I run pptp/l2tp on server 1 and my VPN users connect to it through the valid ip : A.A.A.A.  Also, I run openvpn on server 2 (B.B.B.B).

I want to connect server 1 to 2 and forward all traffic to server 2.  In other words , when my users connect to server 1(A.A.A.A), they can use the internet of server 2 with ip B.B.B.B.

I also tried to connect server 1 to 2 with openvpn  with "redirect-gateway def1" but when it connected completely, it lost its valid ip A.A.A.A and my clients cannot ping A.A.A.A...

How do I get this to work?

Thanks.

edited :
i can connect 2 server via openvpn "site so site" , and they can ping Each other without losing valid ip , but i cannot redirect traffic from server A.A.A.A to B.B.B.B

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you're doing this correctly.  You need to redirect the pptp traffic on BBBB, not the openvpn traffic.

Comment: It might be more useful to the OP to include more specific recommendations that might help him solve his problem.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  But look here, we don't have any information as to OS or software implementation.  I'm very skilled in using OpenVPN on both Windows and Linux, but PPTP implementations will vary.  I also took note that our OP has a box in Iran, and that wipes out a whole array of possibilities by the fact that the government there will ***literally*** put a whip to the back of anyone trying to use OpenVPN.  We can only do what we can.

Comment: The question is tagged linux.